# Spring & Couchbase - No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.sql.Timestamp]

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-couchbase

We have a document that we save to a Couchbase DB. It has a timestamp field:

```
@Document
class Cat{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
private String id;

@Field
Timestamp birthdateTimestamp;
```

We are able to save data into the field when creating the Cat:

```
 Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
 Cat cat = Cat.builder().birthdateTimestamp(currentTimestamp).build();
 catRepository.save(cat);  // extends CouchbaseRepository<Cat, String>
```

And the field can be seen in the DB correctly - `"birthdateTimestamp": 1564570366644`

However, when trying to read the `Cat` from the DB, we get this error:

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.sql.Timestamp]] with root cause 
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.sql.Timestamp]
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.readValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:804)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.access$400(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$CouchbasePropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:869)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter$CouchbasePropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:824)
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:71)
>       at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49)
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:248)
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:221)
>       at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:86)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:236)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:171)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.MappingCouchbaseConverter.read(MappingCouchbaseConverter.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.mapToEntity(CouchbaseTemplate.java:700)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.findByN1QL(CouchbaseTemplate.java:448)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeCollection(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:156)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeEntity(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:162)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.executeDependingOnType(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:135)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.execute(AbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.ViewPostProcessor$ViewInterceptor.invoke(ViewPostProcessor.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.findByCustomerNameAndProjectName(Unknown Source)

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the value is being stored in the DB in an Epoch format.

Instead of trying to convert the epoch directly to a sql Timestamp, you can stored it as a long instead, i.e.

```
@Field
long birthdateTimestamp;
```

Then to convert from the epoch format to a sql Timestamp, you can use something like the following.

```
new Timestamp(object.getBirthdateTimestamp())
```

Comment: so simple... :-)